# Смена картинок при смене темы

Tags: android, android-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно менять иконки или картинки при смене темы.

Сейчас я делаю так, но я считаю это неправильным и хочу узнать какие способы ещё существуют

```
if (Preferences.isDarkTheam) {
    btnRefresh.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.refresh_better_w);
    btnRefreshBookMark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.refresh_better_w);
    btnFilter.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.baseline_sort_24px_w);
    btnMenu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.baseline_better_w);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот ссылка на то как правильно нужно менять картинки при смене темы
http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2014/06/04/changeimageviewsrctheme.html